# Adding Cooldowns to Commands in Python

Tags: python

So I've been trying to add cooldowns to commands in Python without actually stopping the code run. The context is I'm making a JJBA Game with Stands called "JoJo's Legacy", but I can't find a way to make cooldowns work without fully stopping the code. Is there any way I can find a way to create this situation?
code:

```
import random
import time
dummy=300
while True:
    standopt=input("Choose between TWHV and SP.\nIf you already chose a Stand, you're choosing again due to the dummy's hospitalisation.")
    if standopt=="TWHV" or standopt=="twhv" or standopt=="Twhv":
            while True:
                if dummy>=1:
                    Quotes=["I won! You proved every weakness I predicted you had!","Johnny Joestar...you're my ultimate test, and I've accepted this test to become stronger.","Seems my resolve had bested yours, hadn't it?"]
                    BasicMoves=[random.choice(Quotes)]
                    Utility=["Knives Volley (24)","Knives Volley (8)","Pocket Revolver (40)"]
                    Unique=["Triple Muda (90)"]
                    Ultimate=["ZA WARUDO! ORE DAKE NO JIKAN DAZE! (5 second Timestop)"]
                    Action = str(input("Your Stand awaits instructions...(q, e, r, t, standofft, y, h, f, n)"))
                    if Action=="e":
                        print("Barrage (28)")
                        dummy=dummy-28
                        print("Your dummy is now on",dummy,"HP.")
                    elif Action=="r":
                        print("Heavy Punch (30)")
                        dummy=dummy-30
                        print("Your dummy is now on",dummy,"HP.")
                    elif Action=="h":
                         print("Triple Muda (90)")
                         dummy=dummy-90
                         print("Your dummy is now on",dummy,"HP.")
                    elif Action=="t":
                        print(Utility[0])
                        dummy=dummy-24
                        print("Your dummy is now on",dummy,"HP.")
                    elif Action=="standofft":
                        print(Utility[1])
                        dummy=dummy-8
                        print("Your dummy is now on",dummy,"HP.")
                    elif Action=="y":
                        print(Utility[2])
                        dummy=dummy-40
                        print("Your dummy is now on",dummy,"HP.")
                    elif Action=="f":
                        print(Ultimate[0])
                        print("The dummy has been timestopped!")
                        time.sleep(5)
                    elif Action=="n":
                        print(BasicMoves[0])
                        print("The dummy feels taunted! (This means nothing to a soulless figure.)")
                    elif Action=="q":
                        print("Your Stand goes back into dormancy...")
                        time.sleep(1.5)
                        break
                    else:
                        print("Please make a correct input.")
                        continue
                else:
                    break
    elif standopt=="SP" or standopt=="sp" or standopt=="Sp":
            while True:
                if dummy>=1:
                    Quotes=["Good grief...","Get lost.","I take things to heart, you know!!","You truly are the lowest scum in history..."]
                    BasicMoves=["Barrage (69)","Skull Smash (42)",random.choice(Quotes)]
                    Utility=["Revolver (30)","Ora With the Kicks (80)"]
                    Unique=["Star Finger (35)","Inhale (Stun)","One-Hand Their ### (100)"]
                    Ultimate=["SUTAR PURACHINA! Ore ga toki no tometa. (5 second Timestop)","You pissed me off! (Counter)"]
                    Action = str(input("Your Stand awaits instructions...(q, e, r, t, standofft, y, g, h, z, n)"))
                    if Action=="e":
                        print(BasicMoves[0])
                        dummy=dummy-69
                        print("Your dummy is now on",dummy,"HP.")
                    elif Action=="q":
                        print("Your Stand goes back into dormancy...")
                        time.sleep(1.5)
                        break        
                    elif Action=="r":
                        print(BasicMoves[1])
                        dummy=dummy-42
                        print("Your dummy is now on",dummy,"HP.")
                    elif Action=="standofft":
                        print(Utility[0])
                        dummy=dummy-30
                        print("Your dummy is now on",dummy,"HP.")
                    elif Action=="t":
                        print(Unique[0])
                        dummy=dummy-35
                        print("Your dummy is now on",dummy,"HP.")
                    elif Action=="y":
                        print(Unique[1])
                        print("The dummy is disoriented!.")
                    elif Action=="f":
                        print(Unique[2])
                        dummy=dummy-100
                        print("Your dummy is now on",dummy,"HP.")
                    elif Action=="g":
                        print(Utility[1])
                        dummy=dummy-80
                        print("Your dummy is now on",dummy,"HP.")
                    elif Action=="h":
                        print(Ultimate[0])
                        print("The dummy has been timestopped!")
                        time.sleep(5)
                    elif Action=="z":
                        print(Ultimate[1])
                        print("*2x ATK & DEF, 1.5x ATKSpd")
                    elif Action=="n":
                        print(BasicMoves[2])
                        print("The dummy feels taunted! (This means nothing to a soulless figure.)")
                    else:
                        print("Please make a correct input.")
                        continue
                else:
                    time.sleep
                    break
    else:
        print("An incorrect input was read. Please re-enter your choice.")
        time.sleep(2)
        continue
```

Comment: A [mre] should be the **shortest possible** code that serves to demonstrate your _narrow, specific_ technical problem. Don't give us your original program -- write a new program that's centered around letting people see your bug, while being as short and readable as possible.

Comment: As for implementing a cooldown, it's your choice of how to do so. One approach might be to start maintaining a turn counter, and when a choice with a cooldown is used, updating a variable saying at which turn that choice will again be available.